# jfreegraph categoryaxis event

Tags: jfreechart

it's possible in jfreegraph add an event handler on category axis? I have a gantt graph built in swing environment, I would like to add a "mouseclick" event on task description(that appears on left of ), anyone could help me?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a `ChartMouseListener` to your `ChartPanel`; you can examine the `ChartEntity` returned by the `getEntity()` method of the corresponding `ChartMouseEvent`.